# Generate GWT Overlay Types

Tags: java, gwt, jaxb, code-generation

Is there any tool/script/approach to generate Overlay Types automatically from Java bean classes? For example, by putting annotations on fields/getters, possibly using standard JAXB annotations like @XmlElement

There is a duplicate topic here: [Generate GWT Overlay types from Java objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721151/generate-gwt-overlay-types-from-java-objects), but the question has not been answered there. The only answer is to use Protostuff, which is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: What would be reason for the overlay types ? Are you using JSON(P) to call the service layer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to do this, though it is only semi-automated. In Eclipse you can create a code template (Window / Preferences / Java / Editor / Templates) like this:

```
public final native ${type:var} get${nameCamelCase:var}() /*-{
    return this.${name:var};
}-*/;

public final native void set${nameCamelCase}(${type} ${name}) /*-{
    this.${name} = ${name};
}-*/;
```

and give it a name like "get".
Then in any GWT editor you should type "get" and hit Ctrl+Space, then Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you overlay types ? Do you want to use JSON(P) instead of RPC ?
I am using JAXB annotated objects in the RPC layer, that way I do not need 2 versions of the objects. RPC is slow and hard to load test, so in that case I could understand you want to go the overlay way. I am doing it in a few places where it made a big impact.

Comment: Because:  
1) RPC is impossible to auto-test
2) The server is GWT-dependent with RPC
3) On server we have Spring MVC for everything: synchronous or asynchronous. For Spring MVC it doesn't matter. You can change from sync to async and back without even touching the server. With RPC you can only dream of that. We can apply the same filters across the application, no matter for GWT or not  
4) you can review all the request data in simple sniffers like Firebug
5) you can either leave the JSON data on the page for consequent read from your component (useful for Spring forms) or return it with AJAX

Answer (score 0):

As far as the Overlay Types documentation is up-to-date, it is impossible to generate Overlay Type implementation by the generator.

It says:

> The implementation of overlay types in GWT 1.5 does not support
>   Generators defining new JSO subtypes (due to the need to redefine or
>   otherwise extend JavaScriptObject$ during subsequent compilation).
>   This restriction is still in place.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/OverlayTypes

Comment: Interesting idea, but I was meaning generation not by GWT generator, but rather with some generator in Eclipse/Maven/Ant/etc during usual Java build